# Right click on desktop icon then click on menu item

Tags: macos, applescript, right-click

I am able to do the right click mouse event by using below script:

`tell application "System Events"
        tell process "Finder"
            set target_index to 1
            set target to image target_index of group 1 of scroll area 1
            tell target to perform action "AXShowMenu"
        end tell
    end tell`

BUT now I want to click on the menu item... let say "Get Info" then how I meet this goal? any clue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
tell application "System Events"
    tell process "Finder"
        set target_index to 1
        set target to image target_index of group 1 of scroll area 1
        tell target to perform action "AXShowMenu"
    end tell
    keystroke "Get Info" & return
end tell
```

Comment: a short explanation about what is different would be helpful